# Reversing string in python using assignment of strings

Tags: python

```
def reverse(text):
    length = len(text)
    length -= 1
    a = ''
    for pos in range(length/2):
        a[pos] = text[length]
        text[pos] = a[pos]
        length -= 1
    print text
```

While I was coding in codecademy I typed this code and found the error which is:

Does your reverse function take exactly one argument (a string)? Your code threw a "'str' object does not support item assignment" error.

which step am I doing wrong? how to proceed without using .join() or any in-built?

Comment: Strings are **immutable**, you can't assign to a character by index.

Comment: strings are immutable so you cannot use assignment as you would a list, why not just concat to `a` starting in range len(s) down ?

Comment: It looks like you expect this to be swapping characters in your string; even if strings were mutable, this wouldn't accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
text[::-1]
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use [: :-1] or reversed sir

Comment: A simple solution without any slicing or built-ins:

    result = '';
    for c in text:
        result = c + result

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, you have to create a new one.

Try:

```
def reverse(text):
    length = len(text)
    a = ''
    for pos in range(length):
        a += text[length-pos-1]
    print a
```

Answer (score 0):

As I  commented strings as immutable and do not support assignment as a mutable structure like a list does,  you can use a range starting from the length of the string -1 to 0 and concat each character to your a string:

```
def reverse(text):
    length = len(text) - 1
    a = ''
    for pos in range(length,-1,-1):
        a += text[pos]
    return a
```